# How to use run a keyword if testcasename is equal to abc in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I know how can we use run keyword if specific condition is met but i want to run a keyword if testcasename matches.

```
run keyword if testcase=abc.robot
```

does anyone know how can we achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot framework provides several [automatic variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) -- variables that are set automatically by the framework. One such variable is `${TEST_NAME}`.

In the following example, only the log statement in the second test will run:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example 1
    run keyword if  "${TEST_NAME}" == "Example 2"
    ...   log  this is example 2?

Example 2
    run keyword if  '${TEST_NAME}' == "Example 2"
    ...  log  this is example 2!
```

Comment: i am getting error  Evaluating expression 'Test Name =="Test Name" and 'condition2' in 'condition2'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: using it as following run keyword if    ${TEST_NAME} =="Test Name" and 'coach' in '&{GTF}[user_type]'    I register to become a user

Comment: @user7982813: are you saying this exact code is giving an error? I doubt it. I can cut and paste it, and run it directly without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

`Run Keyword If    '${TEST_NAME}'=='<your_test_name>'   <Keyword>   <args>`